# Whats the python equivalent of a `while read ... do; ... done < file` for tab delimited file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm in the process of converting BASH scripts I've written into python (my BASH chops put me in a minority where I'm working).

I've got a BASH `while read` function loop that opens a file and formats the tab delimited content into an HTML table:

```
function table_item_row {
    OLD_IFS="${IFS}"
    IFS=$'\t'
    while read CODE PRICE DESCRIPTION LINK PICTURE LINE; do
        printf "    <tr>\n"
        printf "      <td><img src=\"%s\"></td>\n" "${PICTURE}"
        printf "      <td><a href=\"%s\">%s</a> ($%.2f)</td>\n" "${LINK}" "${DESCRIPTION}" "${PRICE}"
        printf "    </tr>\n"
    done < inventory.txt
    IFS="${OLD_IFS}"
}
```

I can do something like this in python, but, having heard of the `csv` module, I'm wondering if there's a preferred way:

```
for line in open(filename):
    category, code, price, description, link, picture, plans = line.split("\t")
    print "    <tr>"
    print "      <td><img src=\"" + picture + "\"></td>"
    print "      <td><a href=\""+ link + "\">" + description + "</a> ($%.2f)</td>" % float(price)
    print "    </tr>"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
import csv

fields = ('category', 'code', 'price', 'description', 'link', 'picture', 'plans')
table_row = '''\
    <tr>
      <td><img src="{picture}"></td>
      <td><a href="{link}">{description}</a> ({price:.2f})</td>
   </tr>
'''

with open(filename, 'rb') as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile, fieldnames=fields, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        row['price'] = float(row['price'])  # needed to make `.2f` formatting work
        print table_row.format(**row)
```

The `csv.DictReader()` class turns your rows into dictionaries, much handier here because then you can use named slots in the `str.format()`-powered string template.

Comment: You fixed the `fields=`, but missed out the `delimiter='\t'` - I might as well delete my answer though ;)

Comment: Oops, yes, there are tabs there. Fixed.

Comment: hmm, You answered the question as I hoped: and have explained some niceties of dictionaries and string formatting.  But I have to admit for the specific example, I think my original solution is cleaner looking.  Are there specific advantages to using `csv.DictReader` methods?

Comment: The only difference is that a `DictReader` produces dictionaries instead of lists per row, which makes for nicer templating and avoids a full tuple unpacking step.  Your version has to create many python strings for each row (each concatenation results in a *new* string object), mine creates only one new string object, in one step, each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `csv` module.

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open(filename) as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t'):
        category, code, price, description, link, picture, plans = row
```